# Unable to save Excel file from server

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, react-redux, save, aspose-cells

I generate an Excel file using the Aspose library in .NET and the controller returns this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile()
{
  byte[] bytes = null;    
  await Task.Run(() => bytes = GetBytes());    
  return new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
  {
    FileDownloadName = "Template.xlsx"
  };
}
```

On the React front I send the request like this from redux

```
dispatch({
  [CALL_API]: {
    method: HttpMethod.GET,
    types: [
      types.GET_FILE_REQUEST,
      types.GET_FILE_SUCCESS,
      types.GET_FILE_ERROR,
    ],
    endpoint: `getFile`,
    useLoader: true,
    responseType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  },
}).then((action) => {
  if (!action.error) {
    download({
      name: fileName,
      data: action.response,
      type: action.response.type,
    });
  }
});
```

I receive an error whose message is "Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0". On the server I tried saving the file and checked its validity on disk, it is fine. I also changed the response type values on the front and back but the result was always the same.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas where the flaw is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to download the file correctly after these changes on server and client

```
// server
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile()
{
  Stream stream = null;    
  await Task.Run(() => stream = GetStream());    
  return File(stream, "application/octet-stream");
}

// client
dispatch({
  [CALL_API]: {
    method: HttpMethod.GET,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    types: [
      types.GET_FILE_REQUEST,
      types.GET_FILE_SUCCESS,
      types.GET_FILE_ERROR,
    ],
    endpoint: 'getFile',
    useLoader: false,
    cacheBust: false,
    responseType: ResponseType.Blob,
  },
}).then((data) => {
  download({
    name: fileName,
    data: data.response,
    type: data.response.type,
  });
});
```